# Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, response.redirect

I have an ASP with a button and all it does is try to load another page. The page is the Default.aspx and it has two buttons, one to sign up the user (which works fine) and another that just goes to another page.

Here's the code:

```
protected void RP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("~/Processes/RetrievePassword.aspx");
}
```

I have tried with with Response.Redirect, with Server.Transfer, tried also the overload with endResponse set to true and false, but nothing. It just does the postback to the same page.

I have tried using the File.Exists() method to check if the redirect file is there. It is.

```
//Always returns true
System.IO.File.Exists(MapPath("~/Processes/RetrievePassword.aspx"));
```

I'm starting to think that it's something about the web.config, but I'm not sure where to begin on that one (if I am even close, that is).

I have looked for an answer for hours with no success so far.

Any idea?

Comment: does `RP_Click` fire? Is it wired to the button?

Comment: Never ever EVER allow a user to retrieve a password. This function should **always** be implemented as a password _Reset_ feature. Passwords themselves should be stored using an irreversible cryptographic hash.

Comment: That's besides the point, but anyway: the idea is to show a page where the user says "I forgot my password" (millions of them all over the internet). Now back the the problem... any more ideas.

Comment: Show us the .aspx markup for the RP button.

Comment: Here it is: <asp:Button ID="RP" runat="server" Text="Forgot my password" OnClick="RP_Click" />

Comment: @Igor Yes, it does fire. I used breakpoints to be sure.

Comment: Are there exceptions? What happens when the redirect fires? Anything?

Comment: Thanks to everyone, it's been solved. After hours and desperation I decided to go back to Microsoft's basics: I rebooted my computer. I don't know what happened, tried deleting the browser's history, cache, anything. Probably a tmp file? Only the shadow knows. "When logic fails, try the illogic."